# Bottling salad dressing with fruit

Tags: fruit, salad

I'm considering bottling salad dressing but I'm not sure of the shelf life. The ingredients for some are - prunes (or figs), lemon, olive oil, ginger, garlic and water and possibly some xanthan gum.

Can you tell me what the best way to bottle this and how long it will keep once bottled and then how long after when it's opened?

Also, I may consider keeping this as a thicker 'dip' recipe as well. How would I bottle that?

Comment: By "bottle" do you mean heating to sterilize in a sealed vessel (generally called "canning" in the US), or just pouring into a bottle and saving?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22617/how-to-bottle-your-own-homemade-salad-dressing - it's a different dressing, but the answer is essentially to use a trusted canning recipe.

Comment: See related:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34893/is-storing-homeade-dressing-with-garlic-powder-safe/34894#34894  Safe refrigeration of dressing with garlic.